# $q$-analog of Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, big-list, q-analogs

The main motivation behind this is to see whether the 'magic' of q-analogs can be felt in number theory. Obviously for q-analogs to be applied to number theory the parametrization in $q$ must yield a generalization in some way whilst simultaneously keeping the structure in such a way that we are still studying numbers. For example: If in some equations involving q-numbers we are manipulating expressions and suddenly we get an additional '$q^2$ term', as so

$${[n]}_q + q^2= 1+q + 2q^2 ... + q^{n-1}$$

This becomes pretty meaningless in the context of number theory. It's good to wonder whether this is possible, studying a $q$-analog of numbers, as by constructing some q-analog without it arrising naturally we are essentially just doing number theory with some unnecessary parameters. One way I thought to do this was as follows.

Let ${[n]}_q$ denote the $q$-number such that
$${[n]}_q = \frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$$
such that $\lim_{q \rightarrow 1}{[n]}_q = n$.

We have the following rule for multiplication

$${[nm]}_q = {[n]}_q{[m]}_{q^n}$$

Since we can write every number as a product of some primes and their powers $n = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_i^{k_i}$ we arrive at the following $q$-analog expression
$${[n]}_q = {[p_1^{k_1}]}_q{[p_2^{k_2}]}_{q^{p_1^{k_1}}}\ldots{[p_i^{k_i}]}_{q^{p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_{i-1}^{k_{i-1}}}} \\ = \left(\prod_{j=0}^{k_1-1}{[p_1]}_{q^{p_1^j}}\right)\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k_2-1}{[p_2]}_{q^{p_2^jp_1^{k_1}}}\right)\ldots\left(\prod_{j=0}^{k_i-1}{[p_i]}_{q^{p_i^jp_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_{i-1}^{k_{i-1}}}}\right)$$
resulting in the fact that
$${[n]}_q = \prod_i\left(\prod_{j=0}^{\nu_{p_i}(n)-1}{[p_i]}_{q^{p_i^j\prod_{r \leq i}p_r^{k_r}}}\right)$$
(Writing the $p$-adic valuation $\nu_{p_i}(n)$ instead of $k$)

Now we can turn to cyclotomic polynomials

$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\,\,\, 1 \leq k \leq n \\ \gcd(k,n) = 1} (x - e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n}})$$
Note that since all $k \leq n$ (for some prime $n$) is coprime to $n$ if $n$ is prime we get
$$\Phi_n(q) = {[n]}_q$$
(when $n$ is prime)

Because of this we can write any $q$-number as a product of cyclotomic polynomials. For example the obvious

$${[n]}_q = \prod_{d \mid n}\frac{\Phi_d(q)}{\Phi_1(q)}$$

Perhaps more interestingly, using the formula we derived above we can see that

$${[n]}_q = \prod_i\left(\prod_{j=0}^{\nu_{p_i}(n)-1}\Phi_{p_i}\left(q^{p_i^j\prod_{r \leq i}p_r^{k_r}}\right)\right)$$

Note that

$$n = \lim_{q \rightarrow 1}\prod_i\left(\prod_{j=0}^{\nu_{p_i}(n)-1}\Phi_{p_i}\left(q^{p_i^j\prod_{r \leq i}p_r^{k_r}}\right)\right)$$

---

This form of product of cyclotomic polynomials has been [studied by Borwein and Choi](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Eschoia/paper/cyclo1.pdf), who in their paper state that

Any polynomial $P(x)$ with even degree $N-1$ and coefficients $\pm$1 is cyclotomic iff
$$P(x) = \pm \Phi_{p_1}(\pm x)\Phi_{p_2}(\pm x^{p_1})...\Phi_{p_r}(\pm x^{p_1p_2...p_{r-1}})$$
Borwein and Choi's conjecture of the odd degree case is immediately obvious for all $\quad {[2k+1]}_q \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ by the connection presented above

---

At first glance this seems to offer insight into number-theoretic statements through the roots of these equations, and hence Galois theory

The twin-prime conjecture can be re-stated as asking whether there are infinitely many cases where
$$1+q+q^2\Phi_p(q) = 0$$ for $q \in \{x: \Phi_{p+2}(x) = 0\}$. This could allow for a different angle to approach the conjecture, from the perspective of varieties in algebric geometry. One could derive such a polynomial in $q$ for primes with any size gap. Although I'm not sure if this would lead to any progress toward the conjecture, I do think it could reveal some interesting structures.

---

For simple number sums like

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_n$$
where $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$
we have the following analog
$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}{[a_n]}_qq^{\sum_{k < n}a_k}$$
This can also be considered in the case where $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Either way we are left with a sum with 'Fibonacci'-like properties
$$a_0+a_1q^{a_0}+a_2q^{a_0+a_1}+a_3q^{a_0+a_1+a_2}...$$
This can be studied from the perspective of [Lucas sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence)

If we consider the analog to a sum over the divisors of $n$ in terms of the '$q$-divisors' of $n$ (i.e the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_{d \mid n}(q)$) we get
$$\left[n\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{f(d)}{d}\right]_q \rightarrow \left(\prod_{d\mid n}\frac{\Phi_d(q)}{\Phi_1(q)}\right) \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{f_q(d)}{\Phi_d(q)}$$
for example: $f\rightarrow (1-q)$
$$ = \Phi_{d_1}(q)\Phi_{d_2}(q)...\Phi_{d_{i-1}}(q)+...+\Phi_{d_2}(q)\Phi_{d_3}(q)...\Phi_{d_i}(q)$$

---

Another potentially interesting application is the study of $q$-congruences on $q$-numbers. One could look at some

$${[n]}_q \equiv f(q) \quad \text{mod} \,\,\, \Phi_m(q)$$

$${[n]}_{q^k} \equiv \quad ... \quad \text{mod} \,\,\, {[m]}_q$$

This seems to already exist though. Here ([1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0097316521000686), [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.01254.pdf), [3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.10361.pdf)) are some papers that go over it. Although the concept seems to be studied with regards to hypergeometric series, instead of numbers, so this could also be very interesting

---

These are the basic ideas. I would like to know if this parametrization and subsequent generalization of numbers in terms of cyclotomic polynomials is a viable analog to number-theory, or if there is another better analog. Relevant formulas, ideas, related papers, etc. are also appreciated.

$q$-analogs aren't widely used in (elementary) number theory, so this post (depending on the viability of 'number-theortic $q$-analogs') can serve as a starting point.

Comment: "I'm going to keep coming back to this post to add more potentially interesting results, ideas, or questions". I do *not* think it is a good idea to keep expanding your post here to add additional results or questions.  That is something to do on a personal blog page.  Edits to a post are meant to clear up something about what you wrote, not to keep extending it just in order to extend it.

Comment: @azimut the post is already quite long and there is not even a question being asked. It's a list of properties and could benefit from having at least a highlighted question early on. I realize the OP doesn't actually have a blog page, but at the same time the posts here are not really meant to be someone posting a long list and then extending it repeatedly. See  https://math.stackexchange.com/tour. Perhaps a moderator can chime in here.

Comment: What is your question? As KCd writes, your "question" looks more like a blog post to me, perhaps even a research proposal. It is much too long and I don't see what your problem is. Remember that MSE is a QA site. I vote to close. And to be clear, this does *not* say that the math you write is not interesting.

Comment: It appears that the question asked here is: **I have found several results which could reasonably be described as $q$-analogues of results in elementary number theory. (a) Are these new? (b) Are there others? (c) Is there any underlying theory that explains them?**. My followup question: What are those results, both the classical and the $q$-versions?  If this is indeed a fair characterization of your question, can you please add words to this effect *clearly and early* in the post? Some of your sections are more speculative which is fine, but a few clearly delineated statements would be nice.

Comment: I'm surprised this post has so many upvotes, as it doesn't have a clear question and isn't a good fit for this site. This is much closer to a nice blog post. I'm inclined to closet this question as being both too broad and too open-ended,

Comment: I want to close the question as it would indeed be better if I add this to a blog rather than listing random different results that relate

Answer (score 2):

Here are a two somewhat related statements (given as an answer as it is too long for a comment):

- Concerning the multiplicative structure we have
  $$a\equiv r\pmod b \iff [a]_q \equiv [r]_q \pmod {[b]_q}$$
  and as a consequence in particular
  $$[b]_q \mid [a]_q \iff b\mid a$$
  and
  $$\gcd([a]_q,[b]_q) = [\gcd(a,b)]_q.$$
- Let $n$ be a non-negative integer.
  The subspace lattice of an $\mathbb{F}_q$-vector space of dimension $n$ is commonly considered to be the $q$-analog of the subset lattice of an $n$-element set. In particular, the $q$-analog of the binomial coefficient is the Gaussian binomial coefficient
  $$
  \left[n\atop k\right]_q
  = \begin{cases}\frac{[n]_q [n-1]_q \cdots [n-k+1]_q}{[1]_q [2]_q \cdots [k]_q}
   & \text{if }k\in\{0,\ldots,n\} \\
   0 & \text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$
  counting the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_q$-vector space.
  Note that $[{n \atop 1}]_q = [n]_q$.
  The Gaussian binomial coefficient $[{n\atop k}]_q$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[q]$ of degree $k(n-k)$, and as expected by the notion "$q$-analog of the binomial coefficient", we have $[{n\atop k}]_1 = \binom{n}{k}$. All irreducible factors of $[{n\atop k}]_q\in\mathbb Z[q]$ are cyclotomic polynomials, and by the $q$-analog of the Theorem of Kummer the multiplicity of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_d$ in the factorization of $[{n\atop k}]_q$ is the number of carries of the addition $k + (n-k)$ in base $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 problems related to cyclotomic polynomials that are unsolved :

Let $n,m>1$ and
$$A(x) = \Phi_n(x) + \Phi_m(x)$$

1. If $n,m$ are distinct odd primes then $A(x)$ is irreducible.
2. If $A(x)$ factors then one of its factors is a cyclotomic polynomial.

Example :

$$\Phi_7(x) + \Phi_{22}(x) = \Phi_4(x) b(x)$$

$$\Phi_4(x) = x^2 +1 $$
$$ b(x) = x^8 - x^7 + 2 x^4 + 2$$

Comment: This is interesting! A few questions: Is this (1.) only for the sum of two prime cyclotomic polynomials? Or is the result unsolved for the following too?
$$A(x) = \Phi_{p_1}(x)+\Phi_{p_2}(x)+...+\Phi_{p_i}(x)$$

For (2.) Is $A(x)$ the same as in (1.)? If so I think it should be a prime cyclotomic polynomial instead of $\Phi_{22}(x)$, and also check since I think the $x^5$ term is missing in the RHS which should be in
$$\Phi_7(x)+\Phi_{22}(x)$$

Assuming this is just a simple error: Is it hypothesized/conjectured what the value of $n$ in
$$\Phi_{p_1}(x)+\Phi_{p_2}(x)=\Phi_n(x)b(x)$$
is?

Comment: @Mako It only holds for the sum of two ! In both [1] and [2]. And yes there are conjectures about $n$ but I am uncertain what they are and if they were well tested.
However you got it wrong , it is $7$ and $22$ in case [2] and primes in case [1] giving irreducible.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insight!